# javascript use property safety without getting error

Tags: javascript

After a while writing javascript I always have this problem. I always have to check the variable exist then only can use its property otherwise I'll got an error. Like below code

```
if (something) {
  var data = {
    date: moment()
  };

}

var x = new F({
  param: param,
  date: data.date || null //<-- still error
})
```

where something variable can be present or not, then I can't safely use date.date. I have to create a new variable to solve this problem. Like

`if(data){
date = data.date
}`

But is there any shorter solution?

Comment: date: (data || {}).date || null //<-- no error. But looks bad :D.

Comment: Yes, it's a problem but you're making it more difficult than it needs to be. instead of only sometimes instantiating `data`, just do it always, and if the condition passes, add the property. That way you _know_ you don't have to protect against `data` being `undefined` and you only care about the properties it has or not. In fact, you don't need a `|| null` in that case, since if there is no `date` property, you simply get `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the variable data is not being defined when `something` evaluates to false. In that case, when you try to access the property `date` you'll get a reference error. The solution is to always initialize the data variable as empty object:

```
var data = {};

if (something) {
  data.date = moment();
}

var x = new F({
  param: param,
  // now data is defined, so we can safely check if the date property exists on it:
  date: data.date || null
})
```

Note that this method only works when you actually initialize data as `{}`, to prevent TypeErrors when trying to access a property on a type other than an Object.

Comment: `when you try to access the property date you'll get a reference error.` it's TypeError - `date` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm pretty confident that when you try to access properties using dot notation, the script will break with a reference error saying:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`.  A typeError occurs when `data` IS defined, but not of type `Object` but let's say `null`, and you then try to access a property on it. It will say:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of null`

Comment: That's would happen if you never declare `data`. But since you have `var data` the declaration will be hoisted to the top of the function (and outside the `if`), so `data` _will_ be declared but will have a value of `undefined`.